# How to create tmp folder like on my picture?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, temporary-files

I want to create in my custom rootfs /tmp folder such as in ubuntu rootfs for raspberry pi2 from ubuntu.com. Rights drwxrwxrwt I have reached, but number 11(major number?) for tmp and green background color with black word "tmp" I don't understand how to reach.

[image: Photograph of ls -la]

Comment: To the downvoters "tools used for programming" is on-topic.  Would be better to have the image in the question as text, tho.

Comment: 11 means amount of used inodes inside.

Comment: @stark, you may upvote :-) (and no, I'm not a downvoter)

Comment: see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94498/64699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the sticky bit, do

```
chmod +t /tmp
```

If you want an in-memory /tmp instead of on-disk, then add to /etc/fstab the line:

```
tmpfs    /tmp    tmpfs    defaults,noatime,nosuid,size=100m    0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, and if I want on-disk /tmp ?

Comment: If you want on-disk, then why did you accept his answer?

Comment: My mistake.  I originally thought the background meant mount point, but I think it means sticky bit is set.  Edited.